What is the correct view i should add for start that intent?
public class SearchAdapter{
Context context;
public SearchAdapter(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}
class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView userName,statusText,userEmail;
    ImageView profilePic;
    LinearLayout user;
    UserModel model;
    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        user=itemView.findViewById(R.id.search_user_recycler_view);
        userName=itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_name_text);
        statusText=itemView.findViewById(R.id.phone_text);
        userEmail=itemView.findViewById(R.id.email_text);
        profilePic=itemView.findViewById(R.id.profile_pic_image_view);
        user.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
             ** Intent intent=new Intent(context,ChattingActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("userModel",model);
               context.startActivity(intent); **
            }
        });
    }

ChattingActivity should start after click on any item of recyclerView

Explain what the problem is as it is not clear and share the crash stack trace (I read in a comment below that you said it's crashing)

Fairly simple
All you have to do is put the OnClickListener on your itemView like so
itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener {
  // Code to launch your activity 
})

This will make sure that the entire item is clickable

item is clickable already. My app crashing when i try to start new activity

Have you declared the activity in the Manifest?

@RanoshisDas: Use Logcat to examine the stack trace associated with your crash.
